# Change URL every X minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially, it is a slideshow using webpages. After 2 minutes the URL changes to a new page etc.

Home -> (2 minutes) -> Page B -> (2 minutes) -> Page C -> (2 minutes) -> Back to Home

And this continues to cycle through.

Does anyone know if a plugin for this exists and if not how would I go about this using javascript or jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Use a timeout and a client side cookie (not very cross browser compliant).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to a new URL after 60 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="60;URL=http://www.your-next-page.com/page.html">
```

No JavaScript required, although you could create a more pleasing experience with JavaScript assuming you are dynamically changing page contents instead of straight redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are multiple plugins for this... but it is as simple as using a timer and a redirect... if you use jquery you can do this: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/